# Является ли предложение ошибкой ?

Tags: морфология

"А как вы объясните обнаружение в вашем портфеле женского тапочка 37-го размера, принадлежавшего Яблонской?"
Задание было следующее: "Объясните, какие ошибки в выборе форм имен существительных допустили следователи во время допроса. Исправьте ошибки".

Comment: Все предложение - псу под хвост.  "Откуда у вас в портфеле взялся тапок Яблонской?"

Answer (score 2):

Хотя и остаётся приемлемым чаще встречающийся вариант "тапок"/"тапочек", но раз возникает такой вопрос, то ошибка в выборе рода именно этого существительного.  Следовательно, фраза должна звучать так: "...женской тапочки 37-го размера, принадлежавшей Яблонской "

Answer (score 0):

Грамматическая ошибка - муж.род сущ. вместо жен.(тапочек/тапочка)

Речевая: "обнаружение" вместо "нахождение". Объяснить было нужно не почему обнаружили вещь, а почему она там находилась.

Comment: Вопрос о тапках - вообще не вопрос. Ерунда абсолютная. Сейчас посмотрел, известнейшие писатели пишут - он, тапок, и ничего, печатают. Тараканов всегда народ тапком прихлопывал. Аналогично : кроссовок/кроссовка

Comment: Но норма-то всё же жен. род, по крайней мере, в словарях так - тапочки, тапочка,а тапок - кстати, вообще форма разговорная. Если писатели и употребляют, то как разговорное.

Comment: Ну, сейчас чего только не печатают. В я книге и "консерва" видела. Так что, это не показатель.

Comment: Составителям словарей можно повернуться лицом к писательской и народной практике словоупотребления))) Шпрот и шпрота.